# Adding a new variation

Tags: entities, commerce

I'm building a store using the *commerce kickstart* drupal distribution and I'm a beginner with it, however do possess some alternative Drupal 7 experience. Now, I need to add a different product variation type but when I try to add one, I and I want to add a Images field to it, the default Machine name assigned it field_images and when I try to store my variation with this field, I get the message *The machine-readable name is already in use. It must be unique.* - Fair enough you would think, but if I go and check in the existing sample variation types, there's multiple existing variation types that use the exact same machine name, *field_images* this is, why is that? It puzzles me why I should not be able to do the same for a new variation type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add `field_images` to your product type, you need to use the "Add existing field" and not "Add a new field" Then the existing machine name is reused. Following that you can configure bundle specific settings under field "instance" settings, as opposed to the shared "global" field settings.

[image]

Comment: Great Thanks but may you further explain what the `bundle specific settings` vs. `"global" field settings` are for exactly? Thank you!

Comment: @cerr, yes see my answer here: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/57653/difference-between-field-and-field-instance/57683#57683