# How to Filter Node Reference Field Values Using Multiple Views?

Tags: nodes

I have a node reference field called *field_parent_dept*. I re-use this field in several content types.  The list of nodes that can be referenced are provided by a view.  The values are filtered based on logged in user.

I'd like to add this field to a new content type, but the departments need to get filtered in a completely different way.  I need a new view to accomplish the filtering.  It appears I need to create a new field, because the view is a field setting.  *Field settings apply to the field everywhere it is used.*

Are there any other options?

Answer (score 0):

According to my understanding and the following answer, I believe you can reuse that same field. It will get cloned and then you can go and modify the field settings. This will affect only that field instance, specific to the entity/bundle (node/content-type).

Hope this helps!

[Difference between Field and Field Instance?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/57683/57183)

Comment: Thanks for the link it was helpful.  I did try your suggestion but unfortunately the field settings are global.  Once I changed the node reference view in my new content type, the new view was used in the shared node reference across all content types.

Answer (score 0):

If you give that department a different user role, you might be able to create groups of filters in the view that provides the values if you can get current user role as a filter option.

So click the "add/rearrange" next to filters. Then one group of filters for these roles OR another set of filters for the special role.

I can't test it right now but it could be an easy way to handle it.